# Parse a CSV into Perl hash in a sub and return the value passed to that sub

Tags: arrays, perl, csv, hash, reference

I try to parse a csv into hash in perl in a sub, then return value of key passed to sub as an argument. CSV file is like:

```
host1, 12121
host2, 34324252345
host3, 45345
host4, 56363425
host5, 3.1
hostn, 435345
```

And my code is like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
my $host_key = getValue('host1');
print $host_key;
sub getValue {
    my $host_file = 'test.csv';
    my $hostname = $_[0];
    chomp($hostname);
    my %hash;
    open my $fh, '<', $host_file or die "Cannot open: $!";
    while (my $line = <$fh>) {
        my @hostname_lines = split /,/, $line;
        my $hostname = shift @hostname_lines;
        $hash{$hostname} = \@hostname_lines;
    }
    close $fh;
    my $host_value = $hash{$hostname};
    return $host_value;
}
```

When I run this code, my return value would be ARRAY(0x6b72d0) but I expect a return value of 12121

Comment: my $host_value = $hash{'host1'} 

so I expect $host_value = 12121

Comment: Posted, a direct fix for that one error, and a few other options. (I removed a few comments I posted.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You build a hash with values being arrayrefs inside the `while` loop.

So you need to retrieve an element in that arrayref

```
my %host;
...
my $host_value = $host{$name}->[0];
```

what can also be written as

```
my $host_value = $host{$name}[0];
```

where the original array had been `shift`ed so the number is now the first element in arrayref.

---

This can also be done as

```
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    my ($name, @numbers) = split /\s*,\s*/, $line;
    $host{$name} = \@numbers;
}
```

since the first element in `split`'s return list goes into the first scalar, and the rest into the array.

---

The data shows one number for a host on each line. If that is always so, no need for an arrayref

```
my %host;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    my ($name, $val) = split /\s*,\s*/, $line;
    $host{$name} = $val;
}
```

where `/\s*,\s*/` trims spaces as well, or even

```
my %host = map { split /\s*,\s*/ } <$fh>;
```

which has the weakness of not being able to easily check expected data format.